# Express request doesn't end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i made a very simple api using express.js. Here's the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var morgan = require('morgan');
var UserModel = require('../Models/User')


app.use(morgan('short'));
app.use(express.json());


app.get('/getAll', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({auth: true});
})

app.post('/addUser', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    UserModel.create({name, email, password}, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).end({auth: false})
        res.status(200).end({user});
    });

});

module.exports = app;
```

And here's the userModel:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
    },
    {timestamps: false}
);
mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User");
```

This is the main server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const AuthController = require("./Controllers/AuthController");
const PORT = 3001;

app.use("/api/auth", AuthController);


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}..`))
```

This is the db.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const dbRoute = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<stuff>/nodejs-db";

mongoose.connect(
    dbRoute,
    {useNewUrlParser: true}
);
```

So here's the problem. when i try to make a request to this api using Insomnia, the requests doesn't end. Basically Insomia starts sending the request and i  have to wait like 20 secs until i get something on my express terminal. If i end the request manually i get this:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - POST /api/auth/addUser HTTP/1.1 - - - - ms
```

I tried looking online but couldn't find anything useful.
I come from a django backgrond. I'm new to Node and Express js.

Edit:
The problem is only with the posts requests because whenever i make a get request it returns immediately `{auth: true}`.

Comment: `express()` should only be used for the main server, otherwise take `express.Router()`.

Comment: changed  `app = express.Router()` and also all the requests but the problem persists

Comment: How do you establish the connection to mongodb?

Comment: using db.js - added now

Comment: where do you `require("./db")` ?

Comment: Yeah well that was the problem.. Forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
Apparently the problem was that my db connection was on another file.
All i did was to move the content from the db.js file to my server.js file.
I forgot to include my db file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.end()` to `.send()`

```
app.post('/addUser', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    UserModel.create({name, email, password}, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({auth: false})
        res.status(200).send({user});
    });

});
```

Comment: Changed - problem persists